# How to pass values(which are not present in the database) in ANY operator in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I want to execute a query which runs over an array of values provided dynamically and these values are not present in the table.

I have tried passing static values in ANY operator but that doesnt seem to work

```
select
    models.sku,
(sum(models.unitretailprice) * 
     sum(coefficients.unit_retail_price))  +
(sum(models.flag::int) *   sum(coefficients.flag::int)) +

(sum(models.sku_moving_avg) * sum(coefficients.sku_moving_avg)) +
(sum(models.sku_week_avg) *   sum(coefficients.sku_week_avg)) +
(sum(models.sku_week_normal)* sum(coefficients.sku_week_normal)) as baseline,
(sum(models.testing) *   sum(coefficients.f)) +
(5 *   sum(coefficients.p)) +
(0 *   sum(coefficients.a)) as promoIncremental,
(sum(models.basket_dollar_off) *   sum(coefficients.basket_dollar_off)) +
(sum(models.category_per_off) *   sum(coefficients.category_per_off)) +
(sum(models.disc_per) * sum(coefficients.disc_per)) as couponIncremnetal
from 
models  join coefficients
on
models.sku = coefficients.sku
and
models.si_type = coefficients.si_type
and
models.model_type = coefficients.model_type
where
coefficients.sku in ('12841276', '11873916') and coefficients.shop_descr = 'Papercrafting Technology'
group by models.sku
```

Here I want the **sum(models.testing)** to accept and run over an aray of values like 0, 5, 10 , 20 , 25 and hence get multiple rows for each iteration.

Expected query to run:::

```
 select
    models.sku,
(sum(models.unitretailprice) * 
     sum(coefficients.unit_retail_price))  +
(sum(models.flag::int) *   sum(coefficients.flag::int)) +

(sum(models.sku_moving_avg) * sum(coefficients.sku_moving_avg)) +
(sum(models.sku_week_avg) *   sum(coefficients.sku_week_avg)) +
(sum(models.sku_week_normal)* sum(coefficients.sku_week_normal)) as baseline,
(5 *   sum(coefficients.f)) +
(5 *   sum(coefficients.p)) +
(0 *   sum(coefficients.a)) as promoIncremental,
(sum(models.basket_dollar_off) *   sum(coefficients.basket_dollar_off)) +
(sum(models.category_per_off) *   sum(coefficients.category_per_off)) +
(sum(models.disc_per) * sum(coefficients.disc_per)) as couponIncremnetal
from 
models  join coefficients
on
models.sku = coefficients.sku
and
models.si_type = coefficients.si_type
and
models.model_type = coefficients.model_type
where
coefficients.sku in ('12841276', '11873916') and coefficients.shop_descr = 'Papercrafting Technology'
group by models.sku
```

and then for 10

```
select
    models.sku,
(sum(models.unitretailprice) * 
     sum(coefficients.unit_retail_price))  +
(sum(models.flag::int) *   sum(coefficients.flag::int)) +

(sum(models.sku_moving_avg) * sum(coefficients.sku_moving_avg)) +
(sum(models.sku_week_avg) *   sum(coefficients.sku_week_avg)) +
(sum(models.sku_week_normal)* sum(coefficients.sku_week_normal)) as baseline,
(10 *   sum(coefficients.f)) +
(5 *   sum(coefficients.p)) +
(0 *   sum(coefficients.a)) as promoIncremental,
(sum(models.basket_dollar_off) *   sum(coefficients.basket_dollar_off)) +
(sum(models.category_per_off) *   sum(coefficients.category_per_off)) +
(sum(models.disc_per) * sum(coefficients.disc_per)) as couponIncremnetal
from 
models  join coefficients
on
models.sku = coefficients.sku
and
models.si_type = coefficients.si_type
and
models.model_type = coefficients.model_type
where
coefficients.sku in ('12841276', '11873916') and coefficients.shop_descr = 'Papercrafting Technology'
group by models.sku
```

and then for 15

```
    select
    models.sku,
(sum(models.unitretailprice) * 
     sum(coefficients.unit_retail_price))  +
(sum(models.flag::int) *   sum(coefficients.flag::int)) +

(sum(models.sku_moving_avg) * sum(coefficients.sku_moving_avg)) +
(sum(models.sku_week_avg) *   sum(coefficients.sku_week_avg)) +
(sum(models.sku_week_normal)* sum(coefficients.sku_week_normal)) as baseline,
(15 *   sum(coefficients.f)) +
(5 *   sum(coefficients.p)) +
(0 *   sum(coefficients.a)) as promoIncremental,
(sum(models.basket_dollar_off) *   sum(coefficients.basket_dollar_off)) +
(sum(models.category_per_off) *   sum(coefficients.category_per_off)) +
(sum(models.disc_per) * sum(coefficients.disc_per)) as couponIncremnetal
from 
models  join coefficients
on
models.sku = coefficients.sku
and
models.si_type = coefficients.si_type
and
models.model_type = coefficients.model_type
where
coefficients.sku in ('12841276', '11873916') and coefficients.shop_descr = 'Papercrafting Technology'
group by models.sku
```

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are trying to achieve. Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some [sample data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Joining against something that isn't there is usually done using an outer join from e.g. an `unnest(array[0,5,10,25])` to the actual table.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  can you rewrite my query using unnest. I am unable to get results using unnest